# Yii Db Profiler Not Working - 'enableprofiling'=>True

Tags: php, yii, profiling

i have enabled profiling to be displayed in yii as below shown.

```
'db'=>array(
      'connectionString'=>'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=ijob_css',
      'username'=>'postgres',
      'password'=>'allion123',
      'enableProfiling'=>true,
      'schemaCachingDuration'=>604800
   ),
```

but still i am not getting anything displayed under the pages of website and its empty.

before it worked and recently i swiotched off by

'enableProfiling'=>false

why doesn't it work ? i must be missing something.

Comment: is `log` component configured? it has to handle all profiling info

Comment: i'm using : 'enableProfiling'=>true, and it works for me... can't you read nothing from DB?

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan tnx adding this resolved. 'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to main config resolved the issue. 'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',

```
'components'=>array(
      'log'=>array(
          'class'=>'CLogRouter',
          'routes'=>array(
             array(
               'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
               'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            array(
               'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
            ),
```